Modify diagrams in SQL Server 2019 has an error
I have a database which contains 3 tables A, B and C. I have created diagrams for those 3 tables and saved them successfully.
After that, when I modified the diagrams I created earlier, it showed a blank screen and I couldn't even right-click.
Thanks for your support.
enter image description here

Database diagrams are highly version-specific. Did you originally create the diagrams in a newer version of SSMS and you're now trying to open and edit them with an older version of SSMS?

Previously, I created it using Sql Server 2012, then moved to Sql Server 2019 and it ran well for 2 years. In recent days, I wanted to Modify Diagrams again and when I opened it, it only showed a blank page.
